# Is it possible to do doctests in repl.it?

Tags: python, web, doctest, conceptual

I am using the website repl.it to code with python and I was wondering how I would use my doctests when using repl.it. Or any other alternative besides the classic print statement checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in the following way. If you execute the following code on repl.it it will give you the output shown below.

```
'''
Credit to the autho-> @pcorkh1

using doctests
for automatic marking
'''

import doctest

def testing():
    doctest.run_docstring_examples(square,globals(),name="square")

def square(n):
    '''
    returns a square of n
    >>> square(3)
    9
    >>> square(1)
    1
    >>> square(6)
    36
    '''
    return n+n

testing()
name = 'Pete'
age = 35
num = 1

print(f'name is: {name} Age is: {age: ^10} num is: {num}')
```

Output:

```
**********************************************************************
File "main.py", line 14, in square
Failed example:
    square(3)
Expected:
    9
Got:
    6
**********************************************************************
File "main.py", line 16, in square
Failed example:
    square(1)
Expected:
    1
Got:
    2
**********************************************************************
File "main.py", line 18, in square
Failed example:
    square(6)
Expected:
    36
Got:
    12
name is: Pete Age is:     35     num is: 1
```

The code is very trivial and once you understand it you can incorporate into your program. You may need to change the structure of your code to achieve this.